# IndexError: tuple index out of range!! Can't Understand Why this error occurs

Tags: python

I am getting IndexError: tuple index out of range when in run the following code :

```
for filename in os.listdir(slice_path):
    if filename.endswith('.txt') is False:
       continue
    print(filename)
    filepath = os.path.join(slice_path,filename)
    f = open(filepath,'r')
    slicelists = f.read().split('------------------------------')
    f.close()
    labelpath = os.path.join(label_path,filename[:-4]+'.pkl')
    #print(labelpath)
    f = open(labelpath,'rb')
    labellists = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()

    if slicelists[0] == '':
       del slicelists[0]
    if slicelists[-1] == '' or slicelists[-1] == '\n' or slicelists[-1] == '\r\n':
       del slicelists[-1]
    #print(slicelists)
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,filename)
    f = open(file_path,'a+')
    index = 1
    for slicelist in slicelists:
       index += 1
       sentences = slicelist.split('\n')
       if sentences[0] == '\r' or sentences[0] == '':
          del sentences[0]
       if sentences == []:
          continue
       if sentences[-1] == '':
          del sentences[-1]
       if sentences[-1] == '\r':
          del sentences[-1]
       labellist = labellists[index]
       #print(labellist)
       for labels in labellist:
          #print(labels)
          if labels == 1:
              label = 1
          else:
              label = 0
       for sentence in sentences:
           f.write(str(sentence)+'\n')
       f.write(str(label)+'\n')
       f.write('------------------------------'+'\n')
    f.close()
print('\success!')
```

The error they indicating on the terminal is as follows :

```
pointersuse_slices.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_preprocess.py", line 44, in <module>
    labellist = labellists[index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can anyone explain why i am getting this error?? I am trying to label my dataset as 1 or 0. When i remove `index` from `labellist = labellists[index]` it is not correctly labelled.

Comment: indexes usually start from `0` not `1`...

Answer (score 1):

You are starting index at point 1 on line :

```
index = 1
for slicelist in slicelists:
   index += 1
   ...
```

Indexes starting point is `0` so you might be get this error.

Comment: when i changed index value to 0, getting same errror

Comment: Because you increase index down below for loop so when labellist = labellists[index] running your index is 1 not 0